# jQuery - Get user id and article id for each article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-blade

I am trying to save specified article as favorite. So I have a button which should get id of that article, and the id of the user (I will store them into db).
I'm trying to do something like this:
This is a blade...

```
@foreach ( $results['matches'] as $doc => $docinfo )
.
.
.
    <button  class="bookmark"><img id="favorite" align="right" src="{{ asset('/img/icon_add_fav.png')}}"></button>
    <input type="hidden" id="{{Auth::user()->id}}" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" id="{{$docinfo['attrs']['sid']}}" value="{{$docinfo['attrs']['sid']}}">
.
.
.
@endforeach
```

And I've tried so far to output the values in console:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#favorite').click(function(){
          addFavorite();
       });

       function addFavorite(){
          var idUser = document.getElementById({{Auth::user()->id}}).value;
          var idArticle= document.getElementById({{$docinfo['attrs']['sid']}}).value;
      console.log(idUser + '#' + idArticle);
   }
    </script>
```

It only prints to console if the button of the first article is clicked. However, it prints the id of the last article...

For example...

```
<button  class="bookmark">
    <img id="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="15" value="15">
    <input type="hidden" id="1" value="1">

<button  class="bookmark">
    <img id="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="15" value="15">
    <input type="hidden" id="2" value="2">

<button  class="bookmark">
    <img id="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="15" value="15">
    <input type="hidden" id="3" value="3">
```

Here I have three buttons. When I press the second and third one, nothing happens. When I press the first one, it doesn't print `15#1` like it should, but it prints `15#3`.

I want to print the id and the article id when I click the button of the related article...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this bind click on `button`'s class `bookmark`

```js
$(".bookmark").on("click",function(){
var idUser = $(this).next().val();
var idArticle = $(this).next().next().val();
console.log(idUser + "#" + idArticle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  class="bookmark">
    <img id="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="15" value="15">
    <input type="hidden" id="1" value="1">

<button  class="bookmark">
    <img id="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="15" value="15">
    <input type="hidden" id="2" value="2">

<button  class="bookmark">
    <img id="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="15" value="15">
    <input type="hidden" id="3" value="3">
```

Comment: I did, but made a typo and thought it's not working. Now it's ok. Sorry and thx again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using same `id` for all image tags. It's not good. You should use `class` instead of `id`.

So your `html` will look like this

```
<button  class="bookmark">
    <img class="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input class="userid" type="hidden" id="125" value="135">
    <input class="articleid" type="hidden" id="1" value="1">

<button  class="bookmark">
    <img class="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input class="userid" type="hidden" id="135" value="145">
    <input class="articleid" type="hidden" id="2" value="2">

<button  class="bookmark">
    <img class="favorite" align="right" src="http://localhost:8000/img/icon_add_fav.png">
    </button>
    <input class="userid" type="hidden" id="165" value="155">
    <input class="articleid" type="hidden" id="3" value="3">
```

and `Script`

```
  $('.bookmark').click(function(){
          var userid=$(this).next('.userid').val();
          console.log(userid);
  });
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kqjyvokz/)

Comment: But I need unique userId. `Auth::user()->id` gives me the id of the current user. If I'm the user and I want to add article to favorites, then it should save only my id...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution will help you.

```
function addFavourite(userId, articleId) {
    console.log(userId + "#" + articleId)
}
```

When you render HTML

```
@foreach ( $results['matches'] as $doc => $docinfo )
.
.
.
    <button  class="bookmark" onClick="addFavourite(Auth::user()->id, $docinfo['attrs']['sid'])" />
.
.
.
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only have one element with the same `id` - all your buttons have the same `id`.

Wire up the event handler using classes instead, then you can use `this` inside the event handler so you know which button has been pressed.

You can then either use DOM navigation `$(this).next()`, link them using attributes or group them in a parent container.

Using `.next()`:

```
// wire up to the button, not the image
$('button.bookmark').click(function() {
    var idUser = $(this).next().val();
    var idArticle = $(this).next().next().val();
    console.log(idUser + '#' + idArticle);
});
```

Comment: Wrong, 'this' in addFavourite is not visible, actually, 'this' isn't clicked button in that function.
You need to extend function like this addFavourite(element), and when want to call in click function send this addFavourite($(this))

Comment: @NedimHozić you're right - I was trying to keep it in the same format as the original question rather than making it inline and made a small mistake.  The concept is the same: use `this`.